# I want to insert multiple data into a table when selecting multiple choices using checkbox I am trying to insert with insertBatch in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, codeigniter-4

I want to write a method in CodeIgniter 4 that a user will select multiple subjects for a course with its teaching lecturer and the fees, after the multiple check box selection the relevant fields will be filled which are selected and then the user will click on the save button to save it.

in the controller i write a for loop the count the number of checkboxes check and then creating an array to fetch data from HTML form elements and then

in the model i am keeping a method to insertBatch(); calling it in the controller.

it works but some rows are getting 02 or 03 columns are empty.

I just dump the array using var_dump() the output is with an empty value, as per the database entry also the same.

how can I sort it out?

I herewith write my HTML for the creation and the controller code as well the model and the database output.

***THE HTML CODE (mycourse.php - view)***

```
<?php 
if(isset($listSubjects)){ // i am just checking the subjects are fetched
    foreach($listSubjects as $listSubjects){ //writing a foreach to create HTML form input elements 
?>
    <tr class="border border-secondary">
        <td scope="col">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="**subject[]**" value="<?php echo $listSubjects['id'].'#'.$listSubjects['subject_name']; ?>"> <?php echo $listSubjects['subject_name']; ?> <!--  id="gridCheck1" !-->
            </div>
        </td>
        <td scope="col">
            <input type="number" min="0" name="**subject_fee[]**" id="subject_fee" class="form-control" style="text-align:right;" placeholder="" value="0.00" ><!-- onkeypress="calculate_courseFee()" onchange="calculate_courseFee()" onfocus="calculate_courseFee()" !-->
        </td>
        <td scope="col">
            <select name="**lecturer[]**" id="lecturer" class="form-select"> <!-- id="inputState" !-->
                <option value="" selected>--</option>
<?php
        if(isset($listLecturers)){
            foreach($listLecturers as $mylistLecturers){
?>
                <option value="<?php echo $mylistLecturers['id'].'#'.$mylistLecturers['full_name']; ?>"><?php echo $mylistLecturers['full_name']; ?></option>
<?php
            }
        }
?>
            </select> 
        </td>
            <td scope="col">
                <input type="number" min="0" name="**lecturer_fee[]**" class="form-control" style="text-align:right;" placeholder="" value="0.00" ><!-- onkeypress="calculate_courseFee()" onchange="calculate_courseFee()" onfocus="calculate_courseFee()" id="lecturer_fee" !-->
            </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div style="text-align:right;"><!--class="text-center"!--> 
    <button type="submit" name="btn_save" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button>
    <button type="reset" name="btn_reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
    <button type="button" name="btn_close" class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>
</div>
```

***THE CONTROLLER (MyCourse.php - controller)***

```
    for($i=0; $i<=$selected_material; $i++){
        if($i<$selected_material){
           $subject=explode('#',(string)$this->request->getPost('subject[' . $i . ']'), 2);
           $lecturer_details=explode('#',(string)$this->request->getPost('lecturer[' . $i . ']'));
          $Total_subject_fee = $this->request->getPost('subject_fee[' . $i . ']') + $this->request->getPost('lecturer_fee[' . $i . ']');

          $data_subject[] = [
                'course_id'=>$this->request->getPost('course_id'), 
                'course_name'  => $this->course_name, 
                'subject_id'=>$subject[0],
                'subject_name'  =>$subject[1],
                'subject_fee'  =>$this->request->getPost('subject_fee[' . $i . ']'),
                'lecturer_id'    =>substr((string)$this->request->getPost('lecturer[' . $i . ']'),0,1), 
                'lecturer_name'   =>$this->request->getPost('lecturer[' . $i . ']'), 
                'lecturers_fee'=>$this->request->getPost('lecturer_fee[' . $i . ']'),
                'total_subject_fee'  =>$Total_subject_fee,
                'status'  => '1',
                'session_id'  => session_id(),
                'created_by'  => 'xxx'
          ];

          var_dump($data_subject);
       }
    }

    $this->CourseModel->insertCourseSubjects($data_subject); // calling the model function
```

***THE MODEL***

```
public function insertCourseSubjects($data){

      $builder = $this->db->table("tbl_course_subjects");

      $builder->insertBatch($data);

      return true;
}
```

***THE OUTPUT OF THE $data_subject[] ARRAY***

```
array(5) {

  [0]=>

  array(12) {

    ["course_id"]=>string(6) "000083"
    ["course_name"]=>string(15) "G-01 2023 batch"
    ["subject_id"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["subject_name"]=>string(5) "Tamil"
    ["subject_fee"]=>string(5) "10.00"
    ["lecturer_id"]=>string(1) "7"
    ["lecturer_name"]=>string(22) "7#Veerasingam Rajeevan"
    ["lecturers_fee"]=>string(4) "0.00"
    ["total_subject_fee"]=>float(10)
    ["status"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["session_id"]=>string(32) "m16pkq2qrb711c41siatpik4bd2s2mqr"
    ["created_by"]=>string(6) "Rajeev"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(12) {
    ["course_id"]=>string(6) "000083"
    ["course_name"]=>string(15) "G-01 2023 batch"
    ["subject_id"]=>string(1) "3"
    ["subject_name"]=>string(7) "History"
    ["subject_fee"]=>string(4) "0.00"
    ["lecturer_id"]=>string(0) ""
    ["lecturer_name"]=>string(0) ""
    ["lecturers_fee"]=>string(4) "0.00"
    ["total_subject_fee"]=>float(0)
    ["status"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["session_id"]=>string(32) "m16pkq2qrb711c41siatpik4bd2s2mqr"
    ["created_by"]=>string(6) "Rajeev"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(12) {
    ["course_id"]=>string(6) "000083"
    ["course_name"]=>string(15) "G-01 2023 batch"
    ["subject_id"]=>string(1) "6"
    ["subject_name"]=>string(8) "Religion"
    ["subject_fee"]=>(5) "10.00"
    ["lecturer_id"]=>string(1) "8"
    ["lecturer_name"]=>string(29) "8#Shandramohan Shanmugaratnam"
    ["lecturers_fee"]=>string(5) "10.00"
    ["total_subject_fee"]=>float(20)
    ["status"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["session_id"]=> string(32) "m16pkq2qrb711c41siatpik4bd2s2mqr"
    ["created_by"]=>string(6) "Rajeev"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(12) {
    ["course_id"]=> string(6) "000083"
    ["course_name"]=>string(15) "G-01 2023 batch"
    ["subject_id"]=>string(2) "10"
    ["subject_name"]=>string(21) "Business & Accounting"
    ["subject_fee"]=> string(4) "0.00"
    ["lecturer_id"]=>string(0) ""
    ["lecturer_name"]=>string(0) ""
    ["lecturers_fee"]=>string(4) "0.00"
    ["total_subject_fee"]=>float(0)
    ["status"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["session_id"]=>string(32) "m16pkq2qrb711c41siatpik4bd2s2mqr"
    ["created_by"]=>string(6) "Rajeev"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(12) {
    ["course_id"]=>string(6) "000083"
    ["course_name"]=>string(15) "G-01 2023 batch"
    ["subject_id"]=>string(2) "13"
    ["subject_name"]=>string(5) "Music"
    ["subject_fee"]=>string(4) "0.00"
    ["lecturer_id"]=>string(0) ""
    ["lecturer_name"]=>string(0) ""
    ["lecturers_fee"]=>string(4) "0.00"
    ["total_subject_fee"]=>float(0)
    ["status"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["session_id"]=>string(32) "m16pkq2qrb711c41siatpik4bd2s2mqr"
    ["created_by"]=>ing(6) "Rajeev"
  }
}
```

the below image is the table with some empty lecturer and subject fields

[the image of the multiple check box form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQqIp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Solution found that I added an extra controller with a looped index (ex:0,1,2,3....) and then I just placed the index with the selected checkbox value.

***example below***

***in view***

<input type="checkbox" name="indexvalue[]"value="echo $count;"> Test Subject

***in Controller***

$this->request->getPost('subject_name[' . $this->request->getPost('indexvalue[' . $i . ']') . ']');

with the above code, the system works without any errors and the performance is also great.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).